# What is the meaning of `int dummy` in the fillInStackTrace() method in Java?

Tags: java, exception, runtimeexception, throwable

```java
private native Throwable fillInStackTrace(int dummy);
```

This method is called with `dummy=0` when an Exception is created. What is the meaning of `dummy`? Is it the depth of the stack trace to construct?

Update:

```java
public class MyEx extends RuntimeException{
   
    @Override
    public synchronized Throwable fillInStackTrace() {
        Method method = null;
        try {
            Class<?>[] classArray = new Class<?>[1];
            classArray[0] = int.class;
            method =Throwable.class.getDeclaredMethod("fillInStackTrace", classArray);
            method.setAccessible(true);
            Object obg = method.invoke(this, 6);

            StackTraceElement[] trace = ((MyEx) obg).getStackTrace();
            System.out.println();
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return this;
    }
}
```

It seems that dummy is really dummy, it doesn't matter what value I put in, the result will be the same...

I wanted to limit the stack trace size to 3 to consume less memory and also creating exceptions would be faster from an execution point of view. I have a real use case where I need many exceptions but with shallow stack traces.

Comment: Why do you care about it? Just out of curiosity?

Comment: `dummy` is a value that's not gonna be used. I'm guessing here: they needed to define a no-parameters method that does stuff and then calls the native version, and since you can't have to methods with the same name and same parameters they added a dummy parameter that is ignored by the native implementation.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca that's probably right, I tested it(see my update) and it really does nothing.. I was hoping that I can limit the stack trace size somehow (to consume less memory and to be more efficient to create Exceptions)

Comment: Throwing a suggestion here: given your use case you don't really care about that parameter anymore. If I were you I would delete this question and open a new one with your *actual* question (i.e.: how do I limit the size of a stack trace?).

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca, I agree with you but I coudln't find any solution pre Java 9. There is the StackWalking API for Java 9+ which suits my use case but I am using Java 8 :(

Comment: That's why I'm suggesting you open a new question :) (specifying, of course, that you're stuck with java 8).

Comment: OK guys, thanks for the help, created a new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63753190/how-to-get-last-few-stack-frames-instead-of-a-complete-stack-trace-in-java-8
I will leave this question open, I think somebody might still stumble upon this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't mean anything.  It is a dummy argument.

The native code implementation completely ignores the argument.  For example, in OpenJDK 11, the bridge method implementation is as follows:

```
/*
 * Fill in the current stack trace in this exception.  This is
 * usually called automatically when the exception is created but it
 * may also be called explicitly by the user.  This routine returns
 * `this' so you can write 'throw e.fillInStackTrace();'
 */
JNIEXPORT jobject JNICALL
Java_java_lang_Throwable_fillInStackTrace(JNIEnv *env, 
        jobject throwable, jint dummy)
{
    JVM_FillInStackTrace(env, throwable);
    return throwable;
}
```

As you can see, the `dummy` argument is ignored.

---

If you are looking for a way to limit the depth of a stacktrace, the supported way to do this is to use the `-XX:MaxJavaStackTraceDepth=depth` option.